# Add thousands separator to reputation in Stack Overflow blog header

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, design, blog

The Stack Overflow blog is redesigned, and in the new design we are able to log in to the blog. Upon successfully logging in, users are now greeted with a refined header layout that prominently showcases their Stack Overflow reputation and badges.

Could we implement a thousands separator for the reputation count for readability and consist the format with Stack Overflow header?

Screenshots for reference:

**Stack Overflow Blog Header:**

> [image: Blog post header]

**Stack Overflow Header:**

> [image: Stack Overflow header]

Comment: On MSO: [Stack Overflow Blog top bar flair does not use thousands separators](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426232)

Comment: @Arulkumar is this still happening?

Comment: @DavidLongworth Just I checked the blog header, the separator was added. Current screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fi4wT.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thousands separator to reputation was added in the Stack Overflow blog header. Now the format is consist with Stack Overflow header.

**Screenshot for reference:**

> [image: Thousands separator added]